# CircleCI - how to connect to localhost

Tags: circleci

In CircleCI I run an app that I would like to run the tests against:

```
test:
  pre:
    # run app
    - ./gradlew bootRun -Dgrails.env=dev:
        background: true
    - sleep 40
  override:        
    - ./gradlew test
```

On localhost the app is accessible on `http://localhost:8080`. I can see the app start up on CircleCI.

I thought that I would change the host `localhost`:

```
machine:
  # Override /etc/hosts
  hosts:
      localhost: 127.0.0.1
```

My tests work locally correctly. On `CircleCI` they always end up without connection when calling `new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/api");` with this error:

> org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException at SendMessageSpec.groovy:44
>           Caused by: java.net.ConnectException at SendMessageSpec.groovy:44

Comment: Slightly off topic, but I am unable to locate the documentation for `hosts:` on the CircleCI website. Could you provide a link at all for this?

Answer (score 1):

I had to increase the sleep time to something unreasonably big. `- sleep 480`

I think I'll have a look at how to block tests until the app is started.